# ffmpeg equivalent for -movflags faststart for audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, transcode

I have several video and audio files on my server that I wish to stream. I have converted all video files to mp4 and audio files to aac.

Now I am streaming both type of files but it seems audio files are taking longer, much longer, to begin playing than videos. Sometimes I can see it buffering the entire file before it starts playing it.

I am not sure if it has any effect but for video files I use the `-movflags faststart` option and it gets the job done.

I was wondering if there is something similar to be done for audio files to make them start playing faster.

EDIT:

here is how I run the command to convert the files:

`ffmpeg -i OriginalPath.wma -strict experimental -c:a aac -b:a 128k -n SomePath.m4a`

And I use the HTML5 web player to play them from my server.

Comment: What actual files do you export your aac tracks to ? .aac files ? If so, I'd recommend .m4a (the same as mp4 but with a different name often associated with audio-only).

Comment: What is your ffmpeg command and complete console output? How are you playing the files?

Comment: Try adding `-movflags +faststart` to the command in your question.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard that seems to work. I was under the impression that this was only for video files. One question though, why the + sign before faststart?

Comment: The `+` should add it to any default flags (assuming if there are any). Without it I believe it will clear everything but faststart, but I haven't actually looked into this or tested it.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `-movflags +faststart` with MP4 & M4A outputs that just contain audio.

Answer (score 0):

If you have files in m4a (m4a is ipod extension files, so old), then you have to put it into a container friendly for html5, like mp4.

```
ffmpeg -i SomePath.m4a -c copy -strict -2 audio_friendly.mp4
```

I think that your problem is your html5 code for playing this audio file, because the **-movflags +faststart** is only if in you mp4 has videos... this code here is ignored, so in your html file, you have to know the attr  and his options

```
<audio src="audio_friendly.mp4" preload="" controls></audio>
```

The "preload" option have to be your problem, how do you configure it?

> preload
>
> Used for buffering large files; it can take one of three values:
>
> ```
>  "none" does not buffer the file
>  "auto" buffers the media file
>  "metadata" buffers only the metadata for the file
> ```

[The source for html5 audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Video_and_audio_content)